# Why program functionally in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

At work we used to program our Python in a pretty standard OO way.  Lately, a couple guys got on the functional bandwagon. And their code now contains lots more lambdas, maps and reduces.  I understand that functional languages are good for concurrency but does programming Python functionally really help with concurrency?   I am just trying to understand what I get if I start using more of Python's functional features.

Comment: See, for instance,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017621/functional-programming-in-python

Comment: I completely re-worked my answer.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Edit**: I've been taken to task in the comments (in part, it seems, by fanatics of FP in Python, but not exclusively) for not providing more explanations/examples, so, expanding the answer to supply some.

`lambda`, even more so `map` (and `filter`), **and** most especially `reduce`, are hardly ever the right tool for the job in Python, which is a strongly multi-paradigm language.

`lambda` main advantage (?) compared to the normal `def` statement is that it makes an **anonymous** function, while `def` gives the function a name -- and for that very dubious advantage you pay an enormous price (the function's body is limited to one expression, the resulting function object is not pickleable, the very lack of a name sometimes makes it much harder to understand a stack trace or otherwise debug a problem -- need I go on?!-).

Consider what's probably the single most idiotic idiom you sometimes see used in "Python" (Python with "scare quotes", because it's obviously **not** idiomatic Python -- it's a bad transliteration from idiomatic Scheme or the like, just like the more frequent overuse of OOP in Python is a bad transliteration from Java or the like):

```
inc = lambda x: x + 1
```

by assigning the lambda to a name, this approach immediately throws away the above-mentioned "advantage" -- and doesn't lose any of the DISadvantages!  For example, `inc` doesn't **know** its name -- `inc.__name__` is the useless string `'<lambda>'` -- good luck understanding a stack trace with a few of these;-).  The proper Python way to achieve the desired semantics in this simple case is, of course:

```
def inc(x): return x + 1
```

**Now** `inc.__name__` is the string `'inc'`, as it clearly should be, and the object is pickleable -- the semantics are otherwise identical (in this simple case where the desired functionality fits comfortably in a simple expression -- `def` also makes it trivially easy to refactor if you need to temporarily or permanently insert statements such as `print` or `raise`, of course).

`lambda` is (part of) an expression while `def` is (part of) a statement -- that's the one bit of syntax sugar that makes people use `lambda` sometimes. Many FP enthusiasts (just as many OOP and procedural fans) dislike Python's reasonably strong distinction between expressions and statements (part of a general stance towards [Command-Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation)). Me, I think that when you use a language you're best off using it "with the grain" -- the way it was **designed** to be used -- rather than fighting against it; so I program Python in a Pythonic way, Scheme in a Schematic (;-) way, Fortran in a Fortesque (?) way, and so on:-).

Moving on to `reduce` -- one comment claims that `reduce` is the best way to compute the product of a list. Oh, really?  Let's see...:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(12,52)' 'reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, L, 1)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(12,52)' 'p=1' 'for x in L: p*=x'
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 usec per loop
```

so the simple, elementary, trivial loop is about twice as fast (as well as more concise) than the "best way" to perform the task?-)  I guess the advantages of speed and conciseness must therefore make the trivial loop the "bestest" way, right?-)

By further sacrificing compactness and readability...:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import operator; L=range(12,52)' 'reduce(operator.mul, L, 1)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 usec per loop
```

...we can get **almost** back to the easily obtained performance of the simplest and most obvious, compact, and readable approach (the simple, elementary, trivial loop). This points out another problem with `lambda`, actually: performance! For sufficiently simple operations, such as multiplication, the overhead of a function call is quite significant compared to the actual operation being performed -- `reduce` (and `map` and `filter`) often forces you to insert such a function call where simple loops, list comprehensions, and generator expressions, allow the readability, compactness, and speed of in-line operations.

Perhaps even worse than the above-berated "assign a lambda to a name" anti-idiom is actually the following anti-idiom, e.g. to sort a list of strings by their lengths:

```
thelist.sort(key=lambda s: len(s))
```

instead of the obvious, readable, compact, speedier

```
thelist.sort(key=len)
```

Here, the use of `lambda` is doing nothing but inserting a level of indirection -- with no good effect whatsoever, and plenty of bad ones.

The motivation for using `lambda` is often to allow the use of `map` and `filter` instead of a vastly preferable loop or list comprehension that would let you do plain, normal computations in line; you still pay that "level of indirection", of course. It's not Pythonic to have to wonder "should I use a listcomp or a map here": just always use listcomps, when both appear applicable and you don't know which one to choose, on the basis of "there should be one, and preferably only one, obvious way to do something". You'll often write listcomps that could not be sensibly translated to a map (nested loops, `if` clauses, etc), while there's no call to `map` that can't be sensibly rewritten as a listcomp.

Perfectly proper functional approaches in Python often include list comprehensions, generator expressions, `itertools`, higher-order functions, first-order functions in various guises, closures, generators (and occasionally other kinds of iterators).

`itertools`, as a commenter pointed out, does include `imap` and `ifilter`: the difference is that, like all of itertools, these are stream-based (like `map` and `filter` builtins in Python 3, but differently from those builtins in Python 2).  `itertools` offers a set of building blocks that compose well with each other, and splendid performance: especially if you find yourself potentially dealing with very long (or even unbounded!-) sequences, you owe it to yourself to become familiar with itertools -- their whole [chapter](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) in the docs makes for good reading, and the [recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#recipes) in particular are quite instructive.

Writing your own higher-order functions is often useful, especially when they're suitable for use as [decorators](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) (both function decorators, as explained in that part of the docs, and class decorators, introduced in Python 2.6).  Do remember to use [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html?highlight=decorators#functools.wraps) on your function decorators (to keep the metadata of the function getting wrapped)!

So, summarizing...: anything you can code with `lambda`, `map`, and `filter`, you can code (more often than not advantageously) with `def` (named functions) and listcomps -- and usually moving up one notch to generators, generator expressions, or `itertools`, is even better.  `reduce` meets the legal definition of "attractive nuisance"...: it's **hardly ever** the right tool for the job (that's why it's not a built-in any more in Python 3, at long last!-).

Comment: That's very nicely put prescriptive dogma.  Thou shall, thou shalt not.  Very old testament, 10 commandments style stuff.  I happen to mostly agree with you (though I think reduce is a bit of a red-headed stepchild).  Can you please explain why?

Comment: Python 3 hasn't fully abandoned reduce. It is in the functools module, and it's probably still the best tool to use, if you want to e.g. find the product of a list.

Comment: -1 proscribing without explanation. `map`, `filter` and `reduce` **are** higher-order functions.  `itertools` has `imap` and `ifilter`, so how is it better?  shouldn't you be bashing it as well?  list comprehension is syntactic sugar for `map` and `filter` that doesn't lend that easily to encapsulation...  python has also demoted `apply` in favor of `*`, which sucks (you can pass around functions, but not syntactic sugar)...

Comment: your edit adds a few contrived (/ stupid code) examples.  ok, so you showed that lambda produces unnamed functions, which must be a horror for someone who uses lots of it without any unit tests  (how do javascript programmers manage to live in such an environment? oh the horror!).  also, you showed that functional programming in python incurs the overhead of added function calls, while reducing the opportunity for state-related bugs.  the `reduce(operators.mul, ...)` example contains no variables and is *as fast* as your preferred low level implementation!  pitty I can't -1 your post again. :(

Comment: @just, yep, you can just keep ranting in long comments, cowardly refusing to offer **your own** preferred response -- do you have any neural circuits left active besides the "foaming at the mouth" one? The examples I showed, far from being contrived, are ones that happen far too often -- just check Stack Overflow to confirm that. As for bugs and their discovery, simple, clear, transparent code (not convoluted and "clever" gyrations, functional or otherwise) is the first line of defense -- and that implies using each language as it's _designed_ to be used... Javascript included;-).

Comment: I think you are being very myopic about efficiency. You should, of course, use the style that feels most natural for what you are trying to do. This will repay itself many times over in the future when you, or someone else, comes back to study your code. Coming from a functional world view it feels very natural to use `lambda` for smaller or temporary functions where there seems no point in giving them a name. Giving things a name shouldn't be a goal in itself.

Comment: @rvirding, "doing what comes natural TO YOU" even when it's unnatural and contrived *the language you're using* will _not_ "repay itself in the future" when some poor soul is tasked with understanding and maintaining it -- such a crazy argument would justify "programming Fortran in any language" (or s/Fortran/any other language you dislike/!-); just as somebody striving to use a FP language _should_ teach themselves recursion, lambdas, pattern matching, etc, so somebody striving to use a _different_ language should similarly use **that** language in its natural way!

Comment: ...and of course giving things a name is not "an end in itself", but neither, and by a long shot, is going out of your way to **avoid** naming things -- *well-chosen* names (including e.g. for subexpressions which _might_ be left unnamed within a complicated expression) can only help clarity and understanding.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: I posted my answer.

Comment: The reason it's not built-in in Python 3.0 is that you can replace every map and filter with a list comprehension which gives more space for the optimisation. What FP provides is a very short implementation of a bunch of typical algorithms. If it looks better when you use for-s and yields - fine. If it looks better as a `( list comprehension )` - fine. Don't say that it's bad, just because it creates some anonymous entities for example. I can't find a single function in my projects which requires the function name to be known. Debugging... it's usually pretty obvious what the control flow is.

Comment: @viraptor, you seem confused -- `map` and `filter` _are_ still built-ins in Py3 (just with better semantics -- those of a genexp, rather than those of a listcomp -- python isn't lazy like e.g. Haskell, so it does have to distinguish) -- it's `reduce` that's been removed from the builtins (and definitely *not* because it can be replaced by listcomps or genexps -- rather, it can best be replaced by simple loops;-).

Comment: Congratulations to all downvoters for the well-organized posse -- I've never before received so many upvotes *and* downvotes on the same question, clearly I must be hitting you guys (FP one-wayists, looks like;-) where it hurts -- good!-).

Comment: Your criticism of `lambda` is correct. But the question asks about functional programming in Python. You can obviously program in functional style without using lambda. Conceptually, there's *no* difference between named functions and anonymous ones (your `inc` example) - it doesn't make the code more or less functional. You say `sort(key=lambda s): len(s)` is wrong, `sort(key=len)` is correct. That's true, but ''both'' methods are passing a higher-order function. (cntd)

Comment: (cntd) So, you're showing bad code (assignment instead of `def`, not eta-reducing obvious code) and concluding using FP in Python is often bad choice. That's true (Guido said explictly Python is not a functional programming language), but I'm afraid the argument is a bit straw man (no offense). So, great post but I'm afraid other posters (extgreen and Omnifarious in particular) expressed that better. That's why -1.

Comment: Yeah - I was thinking about reduce not being built-in, and responded too quickly. Anyways - downvoted too. Not because I'm FP one-wayinst, but because you're anti-FP one-wayist. I prefer the answers from people who responded in a more balanced way. I think most of your examples are strange and not something I would ever write, even though I use FP-style a lot. I use `reduce` a lot to improve(!) readability.

Comment: @viraptor, "anti-FP one-wayist"?!  You've **gotta** be kidding --  I love Haskell, in particular!  I just don't shoehorn into Python the parts of FP that just don't fit there well, any more than I shoehorn into it what just doesn't fit there no matter how important it is in different languages and paradigms.

Comment: @sdcvvc, I repeatedly mentioned the parts of FP that fit well in Python (including HOFs, though in fact there's no "passing of HOFs as you claim in a call to `.sort(key---)`!-) -- but the OP explicitly talked about "lots of lambdas, maps and reduces", so it would have been really bad to fail to point out problems specific to those Python features (though not quite as bad as downvoting what you think is a "great post" because you think another is even better -- that's just not how SO is supposed to work!-)

Comment: I simply think your post is misbalanced, 80% is criticism of misuse of Python's FP tools. I meant that sort is higher-order, thanks for catching that. (But it doesn't change my argument anyway - it is a use of higher-order function in both cases, and neither version is more "functional" than the other.)

Comment: @Alex Martelli I think you are being very myopic again, "the style that feels most natural for what you are trying to do" is of course dependent on what language you are using. How could it be otherwise? My C-code looks very different from my Erlang/Lisp/Haskell/... code. I honestly don't understand how you could conceive it could be otherwise.

Comment: Alex, could you organize your argument into headings or something?  I'm finding it hard to follow.  I get it that you don't like the implementation restrictions that go with `lambda` (which I paraphrase as "FP is not well supported in Python"), but why rail against the eta-expanded "\ s . len s", which is bad news in any language?

Comment: Note that map(str, l) is much faster than [str(x) for x in l], since you actually add a level of indirection in the list comprehension by having to process the function call

Comment: I'm a FP fanboy, but I agree with this answer. It's just not natural in Python. Ruby is actually better for kindasorta pseudo-functional programming, which is weird since functions are first-class objects in Python and they hardly even exist in Ruby.

Comment: Alex, I love your answers and always greatly benefit from them, even when I disagree in details :-).

Comment: @Chuck The bad news (and an argument that seems to be forgotten in most of the discussion here) is that only the least of us are *free to choose*. I for one are not. I cannot go ahead and choose the language that best suits me and the job at hand. Others decide which language I have to use. Giving up on functional Python means giving up on functional programming at all (not withstanding marginal hobbyist efforts in the evening and on weekends). I need my bread-and-butter language to support my efforts to explore FP, and I wished the Python community had a more sympathetic stance to that.

Comment: You very carefully chose the code to use with `reduce`. My tests show it to be somewhat faster than the 'simple loop' for a very similar case. And it requires no local variables to operate either. `python3 -mtimeit -s'from functools import reduce; import operator' 'reduce(operator.mul, range(1,104))` is 16.9 usec/loop and `python3 -mtimeit 'p=1' 'for x in range(1,104): p*=x'` is 20.3 usec/loop.

Answer (score 25):

FP is important not only for concurrency; in fact, there's virtually no concurrency in the canonical Python implementation (maybe 3.x changes that?).  in any case, FP lends itself well to concurrency because it leads to programs with no or fewer (explicit) states.  states are troublesome for a few reasons.  one is that they make distributing the computation hard(er) (that's the concurrency argument), another, far more important in most cases, is the tendency to inflict bugs.  the biggest source of bugs in contemporary software is *variables* (there's a close relationship between variables and states).  FP may reduce the number of variables in a program: bugs squashed!

see how many bugs can you introduce by mixing the variables up in these versions:

```
def imperative(seq):
    p = 1
    for x in seq:
        p *= x
    return p
```

versus (warning, `my.reduce`'s parameter list differs from that of python's `reduce`; rationale given later)

```
import operator as ops

def functional(seq):
    return my.reduce(ops.mul, 1, seq)
```

as you can see, it's a matter of fact that FP gives you fewer opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot with a variables-related bug.

also, readability: it may take a bit of training, but `functional` is way easier to read than `imperative`: you see `reduce` ("ok, it's reducing a sequence to a single value"), `mul` ("by multiplication").  wherease `imperative` has the generic form of a `for` cycle, peppered with variables and assignments.  these `for` cycles all look the same, so to get an idea of what's going on in `imperative`, you need to read almost all of it.

then there's succintness and flexibility.  you give me `imperative` and I tell you I like it, but want something to sum sequences as well.  no problem, you say, and off you go, copy-pasting:

```
def imperative(seq):
    p = 1
    for x in seq:
        p *= x
    return p

def imperative2(seq):
    p = 0
    for x in seq:
        p += x
    return p
```

what can you do to reduce the duplication?  well, *if* operators were values, you could do something like

```
def reduce(op, seq, init):
    rv = init
    for x in seq:
        rv = op(rv, x)
    return rv

def imperative(seq):
    return reduce(*, 1, seq)

def imperative2(seq):
    return reduce(+, 0, seq)
```

oh wait! `operators` provides operators that *are* values!  but.. Alex Martelli condemned `reduce` already...  looks like if you want to stay within the boundaries he suggests, you're doomed to copy-pasting plumbing code.

is the FP version any better?  surely you'd need to copy-paste as well?

```
import operator as ops

def functional(seq):
    return my.reduce(ops.mul, 1, seq)

def functional2(seq):
    return my.reduce(ops.add, 0, seq)
```

well, that's just an artifact of the half-assed approach!  abandoning the imperative `def`, you can contract both versions to

```
import functools as func, operator as ops

functional  = func.partial(my.reduce, ops.mul, 1)
functional2 = func.partial(my.reduce, ops.add, 0)
```

or even

```
import functools as func, operator as ops

reducer = func.partial(func.partial, my.reduce)
functional  = reducer(ops.mul, 1)
functional2 = reducer(ops.add, 0)
```

(`func.partial` is the reason for `my.reduce`)

what about runtime speed?  yes, using FP in a language like Python will incur some overhead.  here i'll just parrot what a few professors have to say about this:

- premature optimization is the root of all evil.
- most programs spend 80% of their runtime in 20% percent of their code.
- profile, don't speculate!

I'm not very good at explaining things.  Don't let me muddy the water too much, read the first half of the [speech](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs242/readings/backus.pdf) John Backus gave on the occasion of receiving the Turing Award in 1977.  Quote:

> 5.1 A von Neumann Program for Inner Product
>
> ```
> c := 0
> for i := I step 1 until n do
>    c := c + a[i] * b[i]
> ```
>
> Several properties of this program are
>   worth noting:
>
> 1. Its statements operate on an invisible "state" according to complex
>      rules.
> 2. It is not hierarchical. Except for the right side of the assignment
>      statement, it does not construct
>      complex entities from simpler ones.
>      (Larger programs, however, often do.)
> 3. It is dynamic and repetitive. One must mentally execute it to
>      understand it.
> 4. It computes word-at-a-time by repetition (of the assignment) and by
>      modification (of variable i).
> 5. Part of the data, `n`, is in the program; thus it lacks generality and
>      works only for vectors of length `n`.
> 6. It names its arguments; it can only be used for vectors `a` and `b`.
>      To become general, it requires a
>      procedure declaration. These involve
>      complex issues (e.g., call-by-name
>      versus call-by-value).
> 7. Its "housekeeping" operations are represented by symbols in
>      scattered places (in the for statement
>      and the subscripts in the assignment).
>      This makes it impossible to
>      consolidate housekeeping operations,
>      the most common of all, into single,
>      powerful, widely useful operators. 
>      Thus in programming those operations
>      one must always start again at square
>      one, writing "`for i :=  ...`" and
>      "`for j := ...`" followed by
>      assignment statements sprinkled with
>      `i`'s and `j`'s.

Comment: *chuckle*  This is a good argument stating in a more complete and thorough form my presmise that FP is really useful when you have a bunch of transforms and compositions to do and don't really need side effects.  Side effects (aka state changes) make your program harder to understand as is well exemplified by your last little block.  `import itertools; a = create_A_list(); b = create_B_list(); c = reduce(lambda c, ab: c + (ab[0] * ab[1]), itertools.izip(a,b), 0)` is actually easier to understand and less error prone.

Comment: Note that `reduce(+, 0, seq)` isn't syntactically valid python.

Comment: @Jeffrey Harris: sure, did you notice the text preceding the snippet? "if operators were values, you could do something like"

Comment: I'd just like to point out (for the benefit of readers who don't know FP): Making "partial" functions looks a little nicer in a real functional language with curried functions. For example, in Haskell, you'd write `functional = foldr (*) 1`, with `foldr` being the reduce function. And that `reducer` function would be totally superfluous, since it would just be defined as `reducer = foldr`.

Comment: @just somebody: No, I'm sorry, I missed the text preceding.  My fault.  But I'm glad you removed it ;)

Comment: @Jeffrey Harris: np.  However, I'm a bit confused as I removed nothing.

Comment: "Josh Backus" -->  "John Backus".  I highly recommend reading that Turing award lecture (linked above) with an open/curious mind.

Comment: great post, a defining moment in my understanding of functional programming.

Answer (score 19):

I program in Python everyday, and I have to say that too much 'bandwagoning' toward OO or functional could lead toward missing elegant solutions. I believe that both paradigms have their advantages to certain problems - and I think that's when you know what approach to use. Use a functional approach when it leaves you with a clean, readable, and efficient solution. Same goes for OO.

And that's one of the reasons I love Python - the fact that it is multi-paradigm and lets the developer choose how to solve his/her problem.

Comment: Exactly - you use the tool that's right for the job. God help me, I even still do some sysadmin stuff in Perl because ... it's the right tool.

Comment: Its funny, I remember Guido saying, that what he didn't like about Perl was its emphasize on "many ways to do it", whereas Python tried to have one or few "best ways" for every problem. :)

Comment: @Thomas, You can do anything in many ways in any language. The difference is whether one way comes naturally and is easier than the rest. In java it will be loads of layers of abstraction, in lisp it will be an implicit DSL. In perl it will be any way that is short and confusing ;) There's nothing wrong with mixing paradigms - as long as you know that the way you wrote something is simple and tidy. (in other words - sure you can implement a trampoline object and use it in your application-specific mini-vm for a state machine... but do you seriously want that over generators?)

Answer (score 16):

This answer is completely re-worked.  It incorporates a lot of observations from the other answers.

As you can see, there is a lot of strong feelings surrounding the use of functional programming constructs in Python.  There are three major groups of ideas here.

First, almost everybody but the people who are most wedded to the purest expression of the functional paradigm agree that list and generator comprehensions are better and clearer than using `map` or `filter`.    Your colleagues should be avoiding the use of `map` and `filter` if you are targeting a version of Python new enough to support list comprehensions.  And you should be avoiding `itertools.imap` and `itertools.ifilter` if your version of Python is new enough for generator comprehensions.

Secondly, there is a lot of ambivalence in the community as a whole about `lambda`.  A lot of people are really annoyed by a syntax in addition to `def` for declaring functions, especially one that involves a keyword like `lambda` that has a rather strange name.  And people are also annoyed that these small anonymous functions are missing any of the nice meta-data that describes any other kind of function.  It makes debugging harder.  Lastly the small functions declared by `lambda` are often not terribly efficient as they require the overhead of a Python function call each time they are invoked, which is frequently in an inner loop.

Lastly, most (meaning > 50%, but most likely not 90%) people think that `reduce` is a little strange and obscure.  I myself admit to having `print reduce.__doc__` whenever I want to use it, which isn't all that often.  Though when I see it used, the nature of the arguments (i.e. function, list or iterator, scalar) speak for themselves.

As for myself, I fall in the camp of people who think the functional style is often very useful.  But balancing that thought is the fact that Python is not at heart a functional language.  And overuse of functional constructs can make programs seem strangely contorted and difficult for people to understand.

To understand when and where the functional style is very helpful and improves readability, consider this function in C++:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int x)
{
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact
 }
```

This loop seems very simple and easy to understand.  And in this case it is.  But its seeming simplicity is a trap for the unwary.  Consider this alternate means of writing the loop:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2) {
        fact *= i--;
    }
     return fact;
 }
```

Suddenly, the loop control variable no longer varies in an obvious way.  You are reduced to looking through the code and reasoning carefully about what happens with the loop control variable.  Now this example is a bit pathological, but there are real-world examples that are not.  And the problem is with the fact that the idea is repeated assignment to an existing variable.  You can't trust the variable's value is the same throughout the entire body of the loop.

This is a long recognized problem, and in Python writing a loop like this is fairly unnatural.  You have to use a while loop, and it just looks wrong.  Instead, in Python you would write something like this:

```
def factorial(n):
    fact = 1
    for i in xrange(2, n):
        fact = fact * i;
    return fact
```

As you can see, the way you talk about the loop control variable in Python is not amenable to fooling with it inside the loop.  This eliminates a lot of the problems with 'clever' loops in other imperative languages.  Unfortunately, it's an idea that's semi-borrowed from functional languages.

Even this lends itself to strange fiddling.  For example, this loop:

```
c = 1
for i in xrange(0, min(len(a), len(b))):
    c = c * (a[i] + b[i])
    if i < len(a):
        a[i + 1] = a[a + 1] + 1
```

Oops, we again have a loop that is difficult to understand.  It superficially resembles a really simple and obvious loop, and you have to read it carefully to realize that one of the variables used in the loop's computation is being messed with in a way that will effect future runs of the loop.

Again, a more functional approach to the rescue:

```
from itertools import izip
c = 1
for ai, bi in izip(a, b):
   c = c * (ai + bi)
```

Now by looking at the code we have some strong indication (partly by the fact that the person is using this functional style) that the lists a and b are not modified during the execution of the loop.  One less thing to think about.

The last thing to be worried about is c being modified in strange ways.  Perhaps it is a global variable and is being modified by some roundabout function call.  To rescue us from this mental worry, here is a purely function approach:

```
from itertools import izip
c = reduce(lambda x, ab: x * (ab[0] + ab[1]), izip(a, b), 1)
```

Very concise, and the structure tells us that x is purely an accumulator.  It is a local variable everywhere it appear.  The final result is unambiguously assigned to c.  Now there is much less to worry about.  The structure of the code removes several classes of possible error.

That is why people might choose a functional style.  It is concise and clear, at least if you understand what `reduce` and `lambda` do.  There are large classes of problems that could afflict a program written in a more imperative style that you know won't afflict your functional style program.

In the case of factorial, there is a very simple and clear way to write this function in Python in a functional style:

```
import operator
def factorial(n):
    return reduce(operator.mul, xrange(2, n+1), 1)
```

Comment: +1 I'm very greatful somebody undertook the effort to actually *explain*, by contrasting, which aspects might be seen beneficial in a functional vs. imperative approach to a suitable problem. It doesn't matter whether I follow all the conclusions, the important thing is it allows me to make well-informed decisions. If more "functional people" would take this road - as opposed to just *claiming* things - I'm sure FP would get more adoption in the mundane programming world.

Comment: @ThomasH: Interestingly enough I'm not really a 'functional person'. I think it's an interesting and useful paradigm and I can see its advantages. I use my awareness of it to improve my programming in imperative languages. I find most functional languages to have syntax that's rather bizarre. My favorite, in fact, is scheme because lisp has such a regular and obvious syntax. :-) Oddly enough, the one I actually use the most is the C++ template meta-language (thought it's really ugly). :-)

Answer (score 9):

The question, which seems to be mostly ignored here:

> does programming Python functionally really help with concurrency?

No.  The value FP brings to concurrency is in eliminating state in computation, which is ultimately responsible for the hard-to-grasp nastiness of unintended errors in concurrent computation.  But it depends on the concurrent programming idioms not themselves being stateful, something that doesn't apply to Twisted.  If there are concurrency idioms for Python that leverage stateless programming, I don't know of them.

Comment: +1 for tackling the real question instead of jumping directly into meta discussions

Answer (score 7):

Here's a short summary of positive answers when/why to program functionally.

- List comprehensions were imported from Haskell, a FP language. They are Pythonic. I'd prefer to write

> ```
> y = [i*2 for i in k if i % 3 == 0]
> ```

than to use an imperative construct (loop).

- I'd use `lambda` when giving a complicated key to `sort`, like `list.sort(key=lambda x: x.value.estimate())`
- It's cleaner to use higher-order functions than to write code using OOP's design patterns like [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or abstract factory
- People say that you should program Python in Python, C++ in C++ etc. That's true, but certainly you should be able to think in different ways at the same thing. If while writing a loop you know that you're really doing reducing (folding), then you'll be able to think on a higher level. That cleans your mind and helps to organize. Of course lower-level thinking is important too.

You should NOT overuse those features - there are many traps, see Alex Martelli's post. I'd subjectively say the most serious danger is that excessive use of those features will destroy readability of your code, which is a core attribute of Python.

Answer (score 2):

The standard functions filter(), map() and reduce() are used for various operations on a list and all of the three functions expect two arguments: A function and a list

We could define a separate function and use it as an argument to filter() etc., and its probably a good idea if that function is used several times, or if the function is too complex to be written in a single line. However, if it's needed only once and it's quite simple, it's more convenient to use a lambda construct to generate a (temporary) anonymous function and pass it to filter().

This helps in `readability and compact code.`

Using these function, would also turn out to be `efficient`, because the looping on the elements of the list is done in C, which is a little bit faster than looping in python.

And object oriented way is forcibly needed when states are to be maintained, apart from abstraction, grouping, etc., If the requirement is pretty simple, I would stick with functional than to Object Oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

Map and Filter have their place in OO programming.  Right next to list comprehensions and generator functions.

Reduce less so.  The algorithm for reduce can rapidly suck down more time than it deserves; with a tiny bit of thinking, a manually-written reduce-loop will be more efficient than a reduce which applies a poorly-thought-out looping function to a sequence.

Lambda never.  Lambda is useless.  One can make the argument that it actually *does* something, so it's not completely *useless*.   First: Lambda is  not syntactic "sugar"; it makes things bigger and uglier.  Second: the one time in 10,000 lines of code that think you need an "anonymous" function turns into two times in 20,000 lines of code, which removes the value of anonymity, making it into a maintenance liability.

However.

The functional style of no-object-state-change programming is still OO in nature.  You just do more object creation and fewer object updates.  Once you start using generator functions, much OO programming drifts in a functional direction.

Each state change appears to translate into a generator function that builds a new object in the new state from old object(s).  It's an interesting world view because reasoning about the algorithm is much, much simpler.

But that's no call to use reduce or lambda.

Comment: +1 although I don't follow your reasoning on ``reduce``. As pointed out elsewhere ``reduce`` is semantical, while a ``for``-loop is not. Thumbs-up for the emphasis on concepts rather than language constructs.

Comment: @ThomasH: The issue with `reduce()` is unthinking application of functions that can lead of O(N**3) or worse performance.  The semantics are clear (and very nice).  However, this is not Haskell and the implementation is unoptimized and can be surprisingly poor.

Comment: Lambda in Python is useful in "swapping" variable order for functions (mydiv = lambda a, b: b / a, partially applied functions; simplifying a function with a lot of keywords), the key argument in sort, small callbacks (click=lambda: self.eat('food'), lazily evaluated variables (self.hp = property(lambda: self._hp * self.hpMods()), factoring out small functions, placing small functions in the more intuitive semantic order, etc...  Also you can execute statements in lambdas via the exec function with locals(), globals().