# Passing a comparison operator with a value into a function

Tags: python, function, arguments, operators, comparison-operators

I am defining a function where one parameter should be a comparison operator.

I have tried different versions of transforming commands such as float and input

Code I am trying:

```
def factor_test(factor1, factor2, criteria1, text, criteria2):
    bool_mask1 = rnt2[factor1].str.contains(criteria1,na=False)
    bool_mask2 = rnt2[factor2] criteria2
    # Returns values that are TRUE i.e. an error, not an Boolean dataframe but actual values
    test_name = rnt2[(bool_mask1) & (bool_mask2)]
```

`criteria2` should be `> 0.75`:

```
bool_mask2 = rnt2[factor2] > 0.75
```

Preferred would be one parameter where I can put in both the `>` and `0.75`, the function should be used about 15 times, with `!=`, `==` and `<`.

Comment: `lambda x: x > 0.75`?

Comment: Very much related but not exact duplicate: [How to pass an 'if' statement to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665082/how-to-pass-an-if-statement-to-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `operator` module:

```
def factor_test(factor1, factor2, criteria1, text, criteria2, op):
    bool_mask1 = rnt2[factor1].str.contains(criteria1,na=False)
    bool_mask2 = op(rnt2[factor2], criteria2)
    test_name = rnt2[(bool_mask1) & (bool_mask2)]
```

Then call with different operators:

```
import operator

factor_test(factor1, factor2, criteria1, text, criteria2, operator.le)  # <=
factor_test(factor1, factor2, criteria1, text, criteria2, operator.eq)  # ==
# etc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass both a comparison operator and its value as one argument you have several options:

1. **Using [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) functions and [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):**

   ```
   import operator
   from functools import partial

   # simple example function
   def my_function(condition):
       return condition(1)

   two_greater_than = partial(operator.gt, 2)
   my_function(two_greater_than)
   # True
   ```
2. **Using [dunder methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization):**

   ```
   two_greater_than = (2).__gt__
   my_function(two_greater_than)
   # True
   ```
3. **Using `lambda`** (as in [jonrsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952371/passing-an-operator-into-a-function/56952429#comment100443499_56952371))

   ```
   two_greater_than = lambda x: 2 > x
   my_function(two_greater_than)
   # True
   ```
4. **Using a function:**

   ```
   def two_greater_than(x):
       return 2 > x

   my_function(two_greater_than)
   # True
   ```

Applying any of these approaches to your function with several arguments should be trivial.