# map when return value is not required

Tags: python

I have a list of objects and I want to change the value of an attribute of all the objects (to the same value-NewValue).

Is `map()` more efficient than a normal for loop in this situation where the function(lambda) doesn't return any value?

```
map ( lambda x: x.attribute = NewValue, li)
```

vs

```
for i in li:
    i.attribute = NewValue
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892324/why-program-functionally-in-python/1892614#1892614) is very enlightening. Also, if you want to know whether one approach is more efficient than another, use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign in a `lambda`, but `lambda` is just shorthand for a function so you could:

```
def set_it(x):
    x.attribute = new_value
map(set_it, li)
```

compared with the obvious:

```
for x in li:
    x.attribute = new_value
```

A general rule of thumb for `map` vs a `for` loop (whether a list comprehension or written out in full) is that `map` may be faster if *and only if* it doesn't call a function written in Python. So expect that `map` will be slower in this case. Also the straight `for` loop doesn't create and then throw away an unwanted intermediate list so expect the `map` to lose out even more than usual.

Comment: thanks..the second part of the answer is what I was looking for though my example in the question was very bad :D

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work. It is not possible to assign a value in a `lambda` construct.

Comment: Oh, I beg to differ: `lambda x: setattr(x, 'attribute', NewValue)`.