# Python: functional programming with cons, car & cdr

Tags: python, functional-programming, cons, cdr

There is this problem that goes like this:

> `cons(a, b)` constructs a pair, and `car(pair)` and `cdr(pair)` returns the
> first and last element of that pair. For example, `car(cons(3, 4))`
> returns `3`, and `cdr(cons(3, 4))` returns `4`.

Now, I have seen the solution, but I'm wondering if anybody can explain how to actually *think* to reach the solution?

1. `cdr(cons(3, 4))`: in what order are these two functions evaluated? I would normally think that `cons(3, 4)` are evaluated first, but that does not make sense in this case, because `cons(3, 4)` returns a function where arguments 3 and 4 are "integrated", so there is no way of singling out the arguments.
2. It seems to me that `car(f)` returns a function, so how can `cons(3, 4)` return `3`?
   **EDIT**: typo, should be `car(cons(3, 4))` instead of `cons(3, 4)`
3. I am obviously trying to solve this problem because I want to learn Python, but would you recommend me to skip these problems? I am tempted to do so by reading here: [Why program functionally in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892324/why-program-functionally-in-python)

Solution:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

def car(f):
    def pair(a,b):
        return a
    return f(pair)

def cdr(f):
    def pair(a, b):
        return b
    return f(pair)

print(car(cons(3,4)))
Output: 3
print(cdr(cons(3,4)))
Output: 4
```

Comment: ". . .but that does not make sense in this case, because `cons(3, 4)` returns a function". Note what the name of `cdr`'s parameter is and how it's used. The same goes for `car`.

Comment: This is not a good exercise for a beginner. It's a pretty complicated use of nested functions, and is hard to explain clearly.

Comment: And coding like this is almost never done in the real world. It's a little bit related to how decorators work, but more complicated than most of them.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: thanks for helping :) Yes I noticed that, but I just can't understand how one could single out the arguments from a function "f" that is already "made"... sorry, I have no idea how to even explain myself

Comment: If they want you to learn Lisp, why not teach you Lisp (or Scheme)? Sure, Python is multiparadigm, but why reinvent Lisp in it?

Comment: @Barmar: yes, I was kind of hoping that somebody would say that this is not useful in the real world, I just hate giving up without understanding something =)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: this is a question from a dailycodingproblem, that I'm using to teach myself Python, so I'm only trying to become a better programmer by solving stuff like this everyday

Comment: The way it works is that the nested functions are closures. `pair()` remembers the values of the parameters to the outer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

In `a(b())`, `b` will *always* be evaluated first. I do not know of a single exception to this in Python. `a` would need to be a macro for the reverse to be true.

Note what the name of `cdr` and `car`'s parameters are: `f`, as in "function". Each function accepts a function as an argument. This works though because, as you noted, `cons` returns a function.

In `car(cons(3,4))`, `cons` returns a function (locally known as `pair`). That function is then given to `car`, and `car` uses it here: `f(pair)`. In this case, `f` is the function that was passed in. The complicated part here is that `f` is a function that accepts *another* function, and calls it with two arguments. Those two arguments are the data that was given to `cons` originally: `3` and `4`.

---

2. 

`cons(3, 4)` does *not* return `3`, `car(cons(3,4))` does. `cons(3, 4)` returns a function that acts on the data that was given to it. In this case, `car`'s `pair` function ends up throwing away the second passed argument (`4`), and instead returns the first (`3`).

---

3. 

Yes, stay far away from code like this for a while. Passing functions around is quite useful, but this code is more of an experimental toy. It's theoretical code to show a style (derived from a lisp like Scheme based on the terminology). There are many, simpler ways of achieving the same end result.

Practice simple examples of [Higher Order Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (like `map` and `reduce`), become proficient with them, then revisit this code. It will still be difficult to comprehend (because, this code doesn't lend itself to easy comprehension), but it will make more sense.

Comment: Actually, it's probably a Python translation of Scheme code from SICP. CL programmers don't do this, either.

Comment: @Barmar I was going off of the `car` and `cdr`; I thought those were specific to CL. The only lisp I ever learned was Clojure, and it did away with all the obscure names.

Comment: Scheme kept Lisp's car, cdr, and cons names.

Comment: But my main point was that exercises like this use of nested functions are common in SICP, and Scheme is the language it uses.

Comment: Thank you so much @Carcigenicate! I still don't understand it, but I'll try to read your answer many times. Regarding question 1: if `b` is executed first in `a(b())`, how can `a` ever have access to the arguments/code/whatever that was used to generate the function `b` in the first place? `cons` returns a function, but a function that is made up of arguments `3` and `4`, so how can these be "picked out" later, after the function is generated (because `cons` is executed before `car`)?

Comment: *That function is then given to car, and car uses it here: f(pair)*: So in my simpleton head, that means that car would return `cons(3,4)(pair)` ... a function, not an argument...

Comment: @Helen `cons(3, 4)` returns a function that internally has the `3` and `4` saved inside of it (known as a "closure"). If you think of the function as an object (which it is), the `3` and `4` are stored internally as attributes of the object (not exactly, but kind of). If it helps to think of it, you can pretend the function that `cons(3, 4)` returns looks like `def pair(f): return f(3, 4)`. The arguments aren't "picked out" later, the values of `a` and `b` are saved and used when it's called later.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Aha... interesting! Then I think I might understand this on a shallow/conceptual level! Thank you so so much! =) Now I'm super stoked =)

Comment: @Helen If you want to play around with it, try this: `f = cons(3,4)`, which saves the function into a `f` variable, then `print(f.__closure__[0].cell_contents, f.__closure__[1].cell_contents)`. Or `print(*[cell.cell_contents for cell in f.__closure__])`. `__closure__` is the cache of saved data, which you can access.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Very neat, thanks for the tip! I had a typo on my question 2, guess it is still somewhat unclear how `car(cons(3,4))` does not return a function... I see how `pair(3,4)` inside `car` returns `3`, but still the return statement of `car` is `f(pair)`, so why is it not returning `f(3)` = `cons(3)` ... maybe a stupid question, no pressure to answer!

Comment: @Helen yes `car(cons(3, 4))` returns `f(pair)`, but that is equal to `cons(3, 4)(pair)` which is equal to `pair(3, 4)` (the pair from `car`! it's not great that they named all those functions the same, only makes it confusing) whihc returns `3`.

Comment: @Helen Ya, note how `car` ends: `return f(pair)`. It doesn't return a function (necessarily); it returns the result calling `f`.

Comment: @Jasmijn: thanks, but I cannot wrap my brain around `cons(3, 4)(pair)` being equal to `pair(3, 4)` =(

Comment: @Carcigenicate right, sorry, I stand very much corrected, thank you =)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have shown can also be solved in this way.

```
def cons(a, b):
    return (a,b)

def car(pair):
    return pair[0]

def cdr(pair):
    return pair[1]
```

This is how you will use it:

```
lst = cons(1,cons(2,3))

# Get the first element of lst
print(car(lst))

# Get the second element of lst
print(car(cdr(lst)))

# Get the last element of lst
print(cdr(cdr(lst)))
```

#### Output:

```
1
2
3
```

*I'm only showing this so that you can see that there is more than one way to solve that problem, and the way you discovered is very rarely done in python. Anyone thinking to solve this in python will 99% of the time do it the way I've shown here.*

Now on to your problem.

---

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

def car(f):
    def pair(a,b):
        return a
    return f(pair)

def cdr(f):
    def pair(a, b):
        return b
    return f(pair)
```

First let's talk about these functions using some haskell function notation so that you can see the full type of these functions:

#### `cons::(a, b) -> (((a, b) -> c) -> c)`

`cons` is a function that takes two parameters `a`, and `b`, then it returns a function `f` which takes another function which when given the parameters (`a`,`b`), returns `c`, where `c` could be `a` or `b`, or something else. `f` then returns the value of `c`.

What a mouthful!

Another way to think of it is that the function `f` (`((a, b) -> c) -> c`) returned by `cons` is used to forward `a` and `b` to any operator (or mapping function) which wants to act on a `cons`. This operator returns `c`. `f` then simple returns whatever this mapping function returns, which happens to be `c`.

For now don't worry what `c` is. Just think of it the result of applying a function to a `cons`.

#### `car::(((a, b) -> a) -> a) -> a`

`car` defines a possible mapping from `(a,b)` to `c`, and returns the value of calling `f` with this mapping.

`car` takes a function `f` that wants a mapping from the input `(a,b)` to some output `c`. In this case, `car` defines the mapping as `(a, b) -> a` which means any function `f` which is passed to `car` will return the first argument of `(a,b)`, which is just `a`. And that is what `car` will return.

#### `cdr::(((a, b) -> b) -> b) -> b`

Similar to `car`, but the mapping defined by `cdr` returns `b` instead of `a`.

---

*Notice how similar the input for `cdr` and `car` are to the function (`f`) returned by `cons`? This is why I just called their inputs `f`*

---

Now to answer some of your questions:

> `cdr(cons(3, 4))`: in what order are these two functions evaluated? I would normally think that `cons(3, 4)` are evaluated first, but that does not make sense in this case, because `cons(3, 4)` returns a function where arguments 3 and 4 are "integrated", so there is no way of singling out the arguments.

In light of the explanation I gave above, the function returned from `cons` is exactly the same type as the one expected by `cdr`. Now all `cdr` has to do is supply a mapping function to `f` and return whatever `f` returns.

> It seems to me that `car(f)` returns a function, so how can `cons(3, 4)` return `3`? **EDIT**: typo, should be `car(cons(3, 4))` instead of `cons(3, 4)`

`car(f)` does not necessarily return a function. See the type signatures above. It just returns whatever `f` returns and if that happens to be a function, then that's what it will return a function.

In general, `car` returns the first element of a `cons`. In this case, since `cons(3,4)` returns a function (`f`) and this function is passed to `car`, then `car` will supply this function with another function that chooses the first of it's arguments, which is `3` in this case. This `3` is now the result of `car(cons(3,4)`.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: thank you very much for a thorough explanation! I'm afraid I don't understand the haskell notation and the new new way of writing the functions `cons`, `car` and `cdf` are slighly confusing to me. I have read your answer many times now. You explain the steps pretty well, I guess I still just don't understand *why* what happens in each step happens, which is kind of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code You pasted is meant to be used like this:

First, You define Your pair:

```
f = cons(3, 4)
```

After that, You define a function that works on pairs:

```
add = lambda x, y: x + y
```

Now, You can use Your "pair" like this:

```
f(add)
```

output:

```
7
```

So, what it does is: It converts Your pair into a function that can "execute" functions on pairs with the defined pair as arguments. `car` and `cds` can actually "convert" your pair-function back and return an element.

Edit:

In case You are not familiar to `lambda` expressions, see [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).

For now, You could also go with

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

and use it just the same way. :)

Comment: This doesn't really explain what's going on inside the functions, which is where the confusion is.