# pythonic style for functional programming

Tags: python, functional-programming

I don't have much experience with Python. I'm trying to code in a functional style like I'm used to from Java and JavaScript e.g.

```
var result = getHeroes('Jedi')
  .map(hero => { hero: hero, movies: getMovies(hero) })
  .filter(x => x.movies.contains('A New Hope'));
```

I'm trying to do something similar in Python but I can't get the same chaining style. I had to break it down to two statements, which I don't like:

```
tmp = ((hero, get_movies(hero)) for hero in get_heroes('jedi'))
result = ((hero, movies) for (hero, movies) in tmp if movies.contains('A New Hope')
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way in Python to approach the first style?
2. What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: [Why isn't Python very good for functional programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017621/why-isnt-python-very-good-for-functional-programming)

Comment: That javascript doesn´t look very functional actually.

Comment: well, you can do functional, but chances are your collaborators are going to hate you for that mostly (: if you also work with a functional person, go for it by all means (:

Comment: @JoeyMallone neither are JavaScript/Java, but the OP wants to write that way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone who adores functional programming, *don't write in functional style in Python*.

This hard and fast rule is a little ham-handed, and there are certainly ways to do what you're trying to do using typical functional tools like `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` (called `functools.reduce` in Python), but it's likely that your functional code will look uglier than sin, in which case there's no reason to prefer it over something imperative and pretty.

```
result = []
for hero in get_heros("Jedi"):
    movies = get_movies(hero)
    for movie in movies:
        if "A New Hope" in movies:
            result.append((hero, movies))
```

This could be done with a list comprehension, but is probably less readable.

```
result = [(hero, movies) for hero in get_heros("Jedi")
          for movies in [get_movies(hero)] if "A New Hope" in movies]
```

Comment: Your nested `for`-loop example is anything, but Pythonic. What is wrong with generator expressions and comprehensions?

Comment: @EliKorvigo nothing when those expressions can be concise, but the sort of nested comprehension needed for this logic is cumbersome. Actually my logic is wrong -- he wants `(hero, movies) if "A New Hope" in movies`.

Comment: I agree with @AdamSmith here: a nested list comprehension gains nothing in legibility over the explicit nested loops

Comment: @AdamSmith I think the second way is what I wanted, thank you

Comment: @AdamSmith I personnaly would have used a list comp within the for loop, ie `for hero in get_heroes("Jedi"): results.extend([movie for movie in get_movies(hero) if "A New Hope" in movies])`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sure: mix and match as appropriate :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I totally agree with you, but darn does rxpy make it hard.

Answer (score 3):

Generator expressions *are* the Pythonic approach, but a functional solution is possible via a combination of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
mapper = map(lambda x: (x, get_movies(x)), get_heroes('jedi'))
result = filter(lambda x: x[1].contains('A New Hope'), mapper)
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO they way of doing that in a functional style in python (not pythonic actually), using `map` and `filter`:

```
result = filter (
    lambda x: x[1].contains('A New Hope'),
    map(
        lambda x: (hero, get_movies(hero)),
        get_heroes('jedi')
    )
)
```

The pythonic way (not very functional) would be to use a generator expresion:

```
result = ((hero, get_movies(hero)) for hero in get_heroes("jedi") if "A new hope" in get_movies(hero))
```

Comment: generators and generator expressions (including list comprehensions etc) actually ARE typical of functional programming -  FWIW, list comprehensions come from Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use third-party libraries, I would suggest `fn.py` with its syntactic sugar for compositions

```
from fn import F

result = (
    F(map, lambda hero: dict(hero=hero, movies=getMovies(hero))) >>
    (filter, lambda x: 'A New Hope' in x['movies']) >> 
    list
)(getHeroes('Jedi'))
```

You can remove the last element in the composition, if you don't want a list, though stateful iterators/generators are not very functional. `F`-objects wrap callables and make partial application and composition easier. A chain of `F`-expressions is a new function that can be used multiple times. This is closer to functional programming in the classical sense: programs are compositions:

```
program = (
    F(map, lambda hero: dict(hero=hero, movies=getMovies(hero))) >>
    (filter, lambda x: 'A New Hope' in x['movies']) >> 
    list
)

result = program(getHeroes('Jedi'))
# or even
result = (F(getHeroes) >> program)('Jedi')
```

Comment: This is a sincere approach to what could be pythonic and functional actually. I think it would "look" better if you name the function you are building and then apply it separately to the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has suggested something like the following, using [pytoolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.pipe)'s `pipe`:

```
from toolz import pipe

result = pipe(
    get_heroes("Jedi"),
    lambda hs: [{"hero": h, "movies": get_movies(h)} for h in hs],
    lambda xs: [x for x in xs if "A New Hope" in x["movies"]],
)
```